# Changing String Value in Array to Capitalize Each Word in VueJS

Tags: arrays, vue.js, split, vuetify.js

I'm getting an array of objects from API call:

```
"data": [
  {
    "heading_one_of_the_table": 14,
     "total": 8
  },
  {
    "heading_one_of_the_table": 1,
    "total": 7
  },
  {
    "heading_one_of_the_table": 6,
    "total": 7
  }
]
```

and I would like to create a new Array that looks like this:

```
heards:[
  {
    text: 'Heading One Of The Table',
    value: 'heading_one_of_the_table'
  },
  {
    text: 'Total',
    value: 'total'
  }
]
```

I'm trying to make the code to handle if the headers is more than just two items so if I got a response with three object items in each array value the code can create three headers. for example:

```
 "data": [
      {
        "heading_one_of_the_table": 14,
        "heading_two_of_the_table": 8,
         "total": 8
      },
      {
        "heading_one_of_the_table": 1,
        "heading_two_of_the_table": 8,
        "total": 7
      },
      {
        "heading_one_of_the_table": 6,
        "heading_two_of_the_table": 8,
        "total": 7
      }
    ]
```

for the `headers` array will change to be like this:

```
heards:[
  {
    text: 'Heading One Of The Table',
    value: 'heading_one_of_the_table'
  },
  {
    text: 'Heading Two Of The Table',
    value: 'heading_two_of_the_table'
  },
  {
    text: 'Total',
    value: 'total'
  }
]
```

I tried using the `splice` on `"_"` and then using `toString().toUppderCase` but that didn't work. Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that first data row always contains all headers.

```js
const data = [
      {
        "heading_one_of_the_table": 14,
        "heading_two_of_the_table": 8,
         "total": 8
      },
      {
        "heading_one_of_the_table": 1,
        "heading_two_of_the_table": 8,
        "total": 7
      },
      {
        "heading_one_of_the_table": 6,
        "heading_two_of_the_table": 8,
        "total": 7
      }
    ];

const headers = Object.keys(data[0]).map(value => ({
  text: value.split('_').map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1)).join(' '),
  value,
}));

console.log(headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can transform the array.

```
const data = [
  {
    "heading_one_of_the_table": 14,
    "total": 8
  },
  {
    "heading_one_of_the_table": 1,
    "total": 7
  },
  {
    "heading_one_of_the_table": 6,
    "total": 7
  },
]

const transform = arr => {
  const res = []
  for (const datum of data) {
    let value = Object.keys(datum).find(k => k !== 'total')
    let text = value.split('_')
      .map(w => w.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1))
      .join(' ')
    res.push({ value, text })
  }
  return res
}

console.log(transform(data))
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pynw4mg9/2/).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the headers don't work. The transform array should look like this: `heards:[
  {
    text: 'Heading One Of The Table',
    value: 'heading_one_of_the_table'
  },
  {
    text: 'Total',
    value: 'total'
  }
]`

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? You should be able to adapt the return value of `transform` to make your "heards" array.